# Magento 2.4.6: Generate image upload fields as per another model data count in admin form using ui_component

Tags: adminform, magento2.4.6, dynamic, addfield

My simple query is how to generate a dynamic field which will created as per count of another model data in admin form using ui component.

suppose I have a model xyz and data countable in this model is 4, then in my another module, in **admin form** I want to **generate 4 image upload fields using ui component**.

if the above count goes up or down, the number of image upload fields will also goes the same.

I tried a lot but do not got soltuion to loop fields in ui component.

[image]

if anybody knows soultion, please update me.

Thanks.